# What is the logic behind this formatting of the lambda by clang-format?

Tags: c++, c++11, emacs, lambda, clang-format

I am using `clang-format` (version 3.5) with Emacs (version 24.5.2). Here is a simple piece of code formatted by `clang-format` in LLVM style:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word) {
        std::cout << std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0,
                                     [](int cur, char ch) {
                         return cur + (ch - '0');
                     }) << std::endl << "> ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note how it aligned the body and the closing brace of the `lambda`. Is there any logic to this formatting or it's just a lack of support for `lambda`s? Are there configuration parameters of `clang-format` that I need to set to get better formatting?

Comment: I would say it easy to identify the lambda body and where the `accumulate()` function ends.  I believe clang-format also uses 80 column width on source files.  How would you have formatted it?

Comment: @NathanOliver Here the max column is 66, so plenty of space. I would start `return` indented to the right of `[]` and align the closing brace with `[]`.

Comment: I think it wanted to align the 3rd argument (the lambda) with the first argument, while aligning the end of the lambda (the end of the code that accumulate is going to run) with std::accumulate.
It kind of makes sense to me, but I would put `{` on a newline

Answer (score 3):

`std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0, [](int cur, char ch) { return cur + (ch - '0'); })`

Here we have a long function call.  To clean it up, we take the long argument, and we split it onto its own line:

```
std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0,
[](int cur, char ch) { return cur + (ch - '0'); })
```

when we do this, we indent the argument to line up with the `(`:

```
std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0,
                [](int cur, char ch) { return cur + (ch - '0'); })
```

so far so good.  Now we have an open `{`.  Well, that means a new line

```
std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0,
                [](int cur, char ch) {
return cur + (ch - '0'); })
```

with an indent.  Where is the base of the indent?  Well, the start of the `std::accumulate`.  Add 4 spaces:

```
std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0,
                [](int cur, char ch) {
    return cur + (ch - '0'); })
```

then we hit the `}`.  New line, backdent:

```
std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0,
                [](int cur, char ch) {
    return cur + (ch - '0');
})
```

finally, embed this in the middle of a larger expression, and you get the mess you had above.

The above is purely a reasonable story, and not based off expertise of `clang-format`.  I cannot tell you how to make it better.

Comment: The whole question is: why should the base of the indent for `return` be the beginning of the whole statement? It was smart enough to not do that for `[]`, wasn't it?

Comment: Well, there was no new line inside the `[]`. But I agree that the indentation should not be relative to `std::accumulate`, but relative to the (natural) start of the line the `{` is in. I.e., if there was a line break right in front of the `{`, there would be a natural position to that – and indenting should count from there.

Comment: @meir I glanced at some source on google, and they have this column system to remember where to backdent to, and I suspect `[]` isn't setting up the right kind of column start as far as the code is concerned.  One coukd download the code and step through it to confirm, but I was just posting an reasonable guess of what the code was "thinking".

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig The reason the lambda body is indented relative to `accumulate` and not the lambda itself is because often lambdas are used as the 'body' of an algorithm. E.g. `std::for_each(..., [] { /* body */});`. So the intent is to format these like built-in loops get formatted. In the case of using a lambda as a predicate or an operator it makes less sense, especially if the surrounding function call is also embedded in a larger expression.

Answer (score 0):

You might want [`AlignAfterOpenBracket: false`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configurable-format-style-options) to bring that `[]` left.

Aligning after open bracket causes too much wasted space in my opinion, it is a wonder that it is so popular. Use `ContinuationIndentWidth` to control how far indented the continuations should be.

Lambdas still don't align perfectly, but at least your lambda opening isn't a mile to the right. I am not completely happy with clang-format's formatting of lambdas either.